# Displaying JsonArray inside JsonObject into ListView

Tags: c#, json, listview, webview, uwp

I have a json like the image below:

[image: json]

I want to put the json into a listview (inside the listview there is a webview to display the text (which I circled in blue), which is in order according to its index (which I circled in black)).

XAML:

```
<ListView
                                    Name="ListPairOption"
                                    Height="auto"
                                    Margin="5,0,10,0">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:PairClass">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <StackPanel
                                                    x:Name="pilganStack"
                                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                                    Margin="10,10,10,10">
                                                    <WebView
                                                        x:Name="option"
                                                        MaxWidth="600"
                                                        MaxHeight="300"
                                                        Margin="5,5,5,5"
                                                        local:MyProperties.HtmlString="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
</ListView
```

Code:

```
string urlPath = "..../multiple/test/284/4";
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", "token"));
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
try
{
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
    JsonObject questionObject = jsonObject["EXAM_QUESTION"].GetObject();
    int index = 0;
        string c = "";
        string v1 = "";
        string choice = "";
        ObservableCollection<PairClass> itemL = new ObservableCollection<PairClass>(); 
    JsonArray mapArray = questionObject["map"].GetArray();
    foreach (JsonValue mapValue in mapArray)
        {
            JsonArray mapArrayI = mapValue.GetArray();
                foreach (JsonValue mapValueI in mapArrayI)
                {
            PairClass pair = new PairClass();
                        try
                        {
                            if (mapValueI.ToString().All(char.IsDigit))
                            {
                                    c = String.Concat(mapValueI.ToString().Where(Char.IsDigit));
                                        index = Int16.Parse(c);
                                        pair.Ind = index;
                                }
                else
                                {
                                    string v = mapValueI.ToString();
                                        var collection = Regex.Matches(v, "\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
                                        foreach (var item in collection)
                                        {
                                            v1 = item.ToString().Trim('"');
                                                choice = v1;
                                                pair.Name = choice;
                                         }
                                }
                for (int i = 0; i < varian; i++)
                                {
                                    itemL.Add(new PairClass { Ind = index, Name =  choice });
                                 }
                                 itemL.Add(pair);
            }
        }
    }
    ListPairOption.ItemsSource = itemL;
}
```

Pair Class:

```
public class PairClass
    {
        public int Ind { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public PairClass()
        {
            Ind = int.MinValue;
            Name = string.Empty;
            Pilihan = string.Empty;
        }

        public PairClass(int ind, string name)
        {
            Ind = ind;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

I'm having a problem, which can't display data into a ListView (only the last data is shown repeatedly in the listview), as shown below:
[image: listview]

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code, it looks you generated `PairClass` in wrong place, it should be created before map item parsed and assigned value after each map item parsed. I have updated the code below, please check it.

```
try
{
    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
    JsonObject questionObject = jsonObject["EXAM_QUESTION"].GetObject();
    int index = 0;
    string c = "";
    string v1 = "";
    string choice = "";
    ObservableCollection<PairClass> itemL = new ObservableCollection<PairClass>();
    JsonArray mapArray = questionObject["map"].GetArray();
    foreach (JsonValue mapValue in mapArray)
    {
        JsonArray mapArrayI = mapValue.GetArray();
        PairClass pair = new PairClass();
        foreach (JsonValue mapValueI in mapArrayI)
        {
            try
            {
                if (mapValueI.ToString().All(char.IsDigit))
                {
                    c = String.Concat(mapValueI.ToString().Where(Char.IsDigit));
                    index = Int16.Parse(c);
                    pair.Ind = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    string v = mapValueI.ToString();
                    var collection = Regex.Matches(v, "\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
                    foreach (var item in collection)
                    {
                        v1 = item.ToString().Trim('"');
                        choice = v1;
                        pair.Name = choice;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        itemL.Add(pair);
    }
    ListPairOption.ItemsSource = itemL;
}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: To display "pair.Name" successfully displayed on the listview, but I want to display the order "pair.Name" (like the image above which I circled in blue) according to the pair.Ind of JSON (like the image above which I circled in black) )

Comment: Sure, you could order base on the ` pair.Ind` property for itemL.

Comment: Sure, you could order base on the ` pair.Ind` property for itemL.  `var list = itemL.OrderBy(p => p.Ind).ToList();
ListPairOption.ItemsSource = list;`